# MySQL password contains '=' having wrong password issue in spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot in my application and we have Azure Services for deployment as well for MySQL services.

I can connect MySQL with MySQL workbench but it gives me error while deploying the Spring boot application that

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'dev-admin'@'IP' (using password: YES)
```

I assume if my MySQL password contains `'='` then it is having issue while deployment with Spring Boot because I changed my password and removed `'='` and it works.

But those are random generated password and I am not sure if the password may contain '=' in future with other environment deployment.

I am setting MySQL password in application.properties like this

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://hq-dev-xxx-westus-dbserver.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/xxx-dev
spring.datasource.username=dev-admin@dev-hq-westus-dbserver
spring.datasource.password=$AP=5ttfg{(=<WN
```

So my question is how can I assign password having '='?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know [Properties Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)) is a file with a set of key value pairs.

as Java treats the first occurrence of = or : as the key-value delimiter you may put backslash escape character () in your line.

In order to avoid errors, it's a good practice to build it programatically like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class TestSO {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.setProperty("spring.datasource.password", "$AP=5ttfg{(=<WN");
      props.store(System.out, null);
  }
}
```

That would print the correct property assignment:

```
#Sat Jul 28 04:05:29 CLT 2018
spring.datasource.password=$AP\=5ttfg{(\=<WN //this line you have to put in your properties file
```

Comment: I escaped the '=' charachters. Thanks!